# How can I remove country select feature using intl_phone_number_input

Tags: flutter

When the country flag is pressed, the country selection feature should not come and it should not be able to choose a different country.

```
Stack(
            children: [
              InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
                onInputChanged: (value) {},
                cursorColor: ColorConstants.blackColor,
                formatInput: false,
                initialValue: number,
                textFieldController: controller,
                selectorConfig:
                    const SelectorConfig(selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.BOTTOM_SHEET,),
                inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 15.h,
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: TextConstants.phoneNumber,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: ColorConstants.customGreyColor, fontSize: 16.sp)),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  left: 92.w,
                  top: 5.h,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40.h,
                    width: 1.w,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                  ))
            ],
          )),
```

[image: this flag should not be clicked and other countries should be selected]

[image: other countries should be not selected]

Comment: set the `enabledCountries` property to an empty list

Comment: How can I have only turkey in the list?

Comment: Pass country names, for Turkey it will be **TR** `InternationalPhoneNumberInput( countries: ["TR"],`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass country names, for Turkey country it will be `TR`

```dart
InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
      countries: ["TR"],
```

If you are interested to find other countries, you can check `country_list.dart`.